# Jquery UI datepicker using Knockoutjs, momentjs in ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, knockout.js, datepicker, momentjs

I am using the custom binding from Niemeyer. I am having problem when selecting the date with the date picker. It shows the current date instead of the date set in the input tag.

I am some how missing some small thing here not sure though.

Please correct and me and help me move ahead.

Please see the jsfiddle at the following location:
http://jsfiddle.net/q46aw/3/

**HTML**

```
         <div class="page">
           <div data-bind="with: person">
             <input data-bind="datepicker:fromDate, value:fromDate, datepickerOptions: {'dateFormat': 'mm-dd-yyyy' }" id="txtFromDate" />
           </div> 
         <span data-bind="text:person.fromDate"></span>
        </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.datepicker = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var $el = $(element);

        //initialize datepicker with some optional options
        var options = allBindingsAccessor().datepickerOptions || {};
        $el.datepicker(options);

        //handle the field changing
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "change", function () {
            var observable = valueAccessor();
            observable($el.datepicker("getDate"));
        });

        //handle disposal (if KO removes by the template binding)
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
            $el.datepicker("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()),
            $el = $(element),
            current = $el.datepicker("getDate");

        if (value - current !== 0) {
            $el.datepicker("setDate", value);
        }
    }
};
$(function () {
    var demo = demo || {};
    //Constructor for a Person object
    demo.TY = function () {
        this.fromDate = ko.observable();
    }
    demo.viewmodel = (function () {
        //private
        var fromDateJSON = 'Date(1293858000000)';
        var person = new demo.TY()

            .fromDate(moment(fromDateJSON).format('MM-DD-YYYY'))

        //public
        return {
            person: person
        }
    })();
    //hookup knockout to our viewmodel
    ko.applyBindings(demo.viewmodel);
});
```

Thanks in Advance,
Raju

Comment: Your example works, doesn't it? When I select a date it shows it inside the field as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems with your code:

1. You bind your datepicker to `fromDate` twice (`datepicker: fromDate` + `value: fromDate`)
2. Your date format is incorrect, you could use `mm-dd-yy` instead of `mm-dd-yyyy` (see http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate)

You can try here:
http://jsfiddle.net/m7f4z/